# Android 3.x JDBC can not link to Oracle

Tags: android, oracle, jdbc, driver

I have some question to ask.
When I use ojdbc14.jar link to oracle 10g in android 3.x sys, that can not connect to oracle.
But I use ojdbc14.jar in android 2.x or 4.0 sys, it can be work.
In 3.x will throw exception is:

> java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: start=0 end=134
>   data.length=168 index=168 length=134

Here is part of code:

```
private static final String DEFAULT_DRIVER = "oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver";
private static final String DEFAULT_URL = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@192.168.0.1:1521:orcl";
private static final String DEFAULT_USERNAME = "admin";
private static final String DEFAULT_PASSWORD = "admin";

try {
    Class sClass = java.lang.Class.forName(driverClass);
    conn = DriverManager.getConnection(DEFAULT_URL, DEFAULT_USERNAME, DEFAULT_PASSWORD);
    setState(conn.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE, ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY));

} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```